# Searching the docs for commands that use a particular option

Tags: documentation

Concrete example:
Pressing F1 on `ListPlot` brings up the documentation page. As an example, Exclusions is not an option for this command. Going to Exclusions page says that this option applies to certain commands (like Plot, Plot3D and NIntegrate)

Is there a way to search through docs to get a complete list of commands that allow for Exclusions as an option without having to discover this individually?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the ["WolframLanguageSymbol"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/WolframLanguageSymbol.html) entity type,

```
Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Exclusions"]["SymbolsUsingAsOption"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful and exactly what I was looking for. My first thought is that even if I had reached the page, I would have returned empty handed on multiple tries.